# how to use scrolling in iframe in fancybox 3?

Tags: iframe, fancybox-3

I'm trying to use `iframe` with in fancyapp 3 and I need to set the parameters `preload` and `scrolling` to `false` and `auto`, but with my current code I'm not able to do so.

Can you please check what it is wrong in it?

Follows the code:

```
<script>
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    iframe : {
    scrolling: 'auto',
            css : {
            width : '600px'
        }
        }
});
</script>

<a data-fancybox data "http://www.test.com">show</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    speed: 230,
    infobar: false,
    buttons: false,
    fullScreen: false,
    thumbs: false,
    closeBtn: false,
    iframe: {
        scrolling: 'yes' //'no'//'auto'
    }
});
```